# How to create a dataset out of the entities?

Tags: filtering, dataset, associations, entity

I am working on learning how to create a dataset from a series of entities.
I have the following function that finds all properties of a certain entity:

```
EntityValueAssociation[entity_Entity]:=Module[{entitytype},entitytype=Level[entity,1][[1]];
EntityValue[entity,EntityProperties[entitytype],"NonMissingPropertyAssociation"]]
EntityValueAssociation[str_String]:=Module[{entitytype,entity},entity=Interpreter["Entity"][str];entitytype=Level[entity,1][[1]];
EntityValue[entity,EntityProperties[entitytype],"NonMissingPropertyAssociation"]]
```

I can use this to create a dataset for example buildings.
I have tried accessing specific elements from a test dataset of the Big Apple's Empire State Building and Chrysler Building as entries.
Here is my code:

```
buildings = {Entity["Building", 
    "EmpireStateBuilding::h583b"], Entity["Building", 
    "ChryslerBuilding::3b77k"]}
buildingsdataset = 
 Dataset[AssociationMap[EntityValueAssociation, buildings]]
```

[image]

Here is an image of the process of querying the dataset.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The issue you are running into is that your keys are [`EntityProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityProperty.html) objects and not strings.

With `buildingsdataset` from op, then

```
buildingsdataset[All, Key[EntityProperty["Building", "Countries"]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can simplify things by using [`CanonicalName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html) on the keys to get their string representations.  Actually, you can simply the whole creation of the dataset.

```
buildingsdataset2 =
 Dataset[
  AssociationThread[
   buildings
   , KeyMap[CanonicalName] /@ 
    DeleteMissing /@ Normal@Through[buildings["Dataset"]]
   ]
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
buildingsdataset2[All, "Cities"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In `buildingsdataset2` the building keys are still entities.  You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> natural language input method with keyboard <kbd>Enter</kbd> (not Shift+Enter or numpad Enter) as a shortcut. For example

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> Empire State Building <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Hope this helps.

Comment: Entity is misspelled.

Comment: I am working on filtering the entities into a class with only buildings of a specified height such as 40 stories.
How can I do this if buildingsdataset[Select[All, #FloorCount > 40 &]] returns an output with errors?

Comment: @PeterBurbery Not at my computer but removing `All, ` should do it. See the docs for `Select` with `Query` which is what the query syntax of `Dataset` is using.